# Use of the definite article before superlative adjectives

Tags: definite-article, superlatives

> We achieve the best financial outcomes through **highest ethical standards** according to our Compliance Code, cost controlling, and protecting our assets, environment, and people.

Is it correct to write this sentence without the article *the* before the superlative adjective *highest*?

Comment: No, superlatives require a definite article before them.

Answer (score 2):

The definite article is required before **highest**, as superlatives need a definite article before them.

> We achieve the best financial outcomes through **the** highest ethical standards according to our Compliance Code, cost controlling, and protecting our assets, environment, and people.